# Automatically resizing font-size in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am currently trying to resize font-size to fit inside a fixed size div. I found this interesting piece of javascript code doing the job very well

```
      $('#defect-text div').css('font-size', '1em');

            while ($('#defect-text div').height() > $('#defect-text').height()) {
                $('#defect-text div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#defect-text div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px");
            }
```

For the following HTML code

```
<div ng-repeat="defect in surface.defects" class="new-page">
           <div id="defect-text">
                                    <div>
                                        <div id="defect-title">{{ 'TYPE' | translate }}:</div>
                                        {{ defect.type }}
                                        <div id="defect-title">Emplacement du défaut:</div>
                                        {{ defect.location }}
                                        <div id="defect-title">Dimension du défaut:</div>
                                        {{ defect.dimension }}
                                        <div id="defect-title">Actions suggérées:</div>
                                        {{ defect.future_operation }}
                                        <div id="defect-title">Détail technique du défaut:</div>
                                        {{ defect.description }}</div>
                                </div></div>
```

However, since the different div are inside an ng-repeat expression, my piece of javascript code will resize the font of every container with the desired size of the first one. Is there a way to change to code to select the current element of the ng-repeat and change only it's own css to fit the container?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is actually one of scope:

```
$('#defect-text div').css('font-size'...)
```

You're selecting ALL `<div>` descendants (no matter how deep) of the `id="defect-text"` element and modifying them at this time.  Technically an ID *MUST* be unique (behavior is not well defined if you have multiple elements with the same ID), and I think your selector is grabbing ALL of the `<div>` contained within ANY `#defect-text` elements, which is probably a lot broader than you want, inside of this particular loop.

I would recommend modifying your ng-repeat block and replacing the ID using the angular expression language like

```
<div id="{{ defect.id }}">
```

then you can use `$("#"+defect.id + " div")` to get all `<div>` descendants of a unique defect.

I'd also consider using the child selector `"> div"` instead of all descendants.

Comment: Yeah it worked ! I simply had to put my resizing code into a loop to iterate over the different defects in order to modify the Jquery selector everytime. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why did this get unmarked as an answer?  It worked, and nobody posted a better one...

Comment: Why do my question have not been upvoted or something? I think it was well asked...